# Div class browser height

Tags: html, css, magento

We are looking for a solution for our shop to give a div the browser height. We have the shop bit.ly/1bR9WPO and at this shop you see the left column with the menu (class = .leftside). At the moment this div has a height of 1800px. The only problem is that when you scroll down the left side is much longer then the right part and if you go to a page that is more then 1800px it will stay that height. We want it to be always the browser height.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: ...and what are we, Professor Charles Xavier....without a code or fiddle...reading through mind??? please post some code, not your site url...

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
height:1800px;
}
.wrapper{
height:100%;
}
.leftside{
height:100%;
}
.page{
height:98%;//taking in to account your margins throught the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

For the main wrapper, add `position:absolute`

```
.wrapper {
width: 1200px;
position: absolute;
}
```

For the left side bar adding also `position:absolute` and `top:0` and `height:100%`

```
.leftside{
position: absolute;
width: 230px;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

For the page div add `position:relative` and `left:250px` (230px of leftside widh + 20px of margin)

```
.page{position: relative;
margin-top: 40px;
left: 250px;
float: left;
width: 762px;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px 20px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

Comment: @Coen try above code can help you and check new examples using googling